# Data Structures & Techniques for operating on large data volumes (1 mln. recs and more)

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, large-data

A WPF .NET 4.5 app that I have been developing, initially to work on small data volumes, now works on much larger data volumes in the region of 1 million and more and of course I started running out of memory. The data comes from a MS SQL DB and data processing needs to be loaded to a local data structure, because this data is then transformed / processed / references by the code in CLR a continuous and uninterrupted data access is required, however not all data has to be loaded into memory straight away, but only when it is actually accessed. As a small example an Inverse Distance Interpolator uses this data to produce interpolated maps and all data needs to be passed to it for a continuous grid generation.

I have re-written some parts of the app for processing data, such as only load x amount of rows at any given time and implement a sliding window approach to data processing which works. However doing this for the rest of the app will require some time investment and I wonder if there can be a more robust and standard way of approaching this design problem (there has to be, I am not the first one)?

tldr; Does C# provide any data structures or techniques for accessing large data amounts in an interrupted manner, so it behaves like a IEnumerable but data is not in memory until it is actually accessed or required, or is it completely up to me to manage memory usage? My ideal would be a structure that would automatically implement a buffer like mechanism and load in more data as of when that data is accessed and freeing memory from the data that has been accessed and no longer of interest. Like some DataTable with an internal buffer maybe?

Comment: Maybe .NET is the wrong tool for this? Look at SSIS. Also, FYI, it would be .NET that had any such tools, not C#.

Comment: Do you normalize the data in memory? Ie in your data structures?

Comment: Can you give a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @JohnSaunders, of course. Good point, but the libs that I use in my mappping and production of grids is written in .NET. I assume this is where your suggestion of SSIS comes in - to stop doing this in .NET and do in SQL? However I have libraries in NET that I need to get this large data to, SSIS probably will not help with that, will it?

Comment: @Grantly thanks, are you asking if I can normalise the data that I need to access to save memory or asking if my data undergoes normalisation when I access it? When I access data, it is normalised already and I just need to pass it to libraries for consumption so they can do their processing using this data. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @LeeGary Thanks, a little tricky to do that, so let me ask you back, what part of my problem would it help you understand that you cannot understand without an example? My problem should be general enough, no? :¬)

Comment: @sergey yeah that sounds optimal. If you were asking c# to hold repeated strings for example like place names, products, etc ... the memory use is mainly redundant and can be greatly improved. You can also vastly reduce memory use by using small types like 16 bit integers and scaling factors, instead of real numbers etc

Comment: @Grantly thanks for the thought, already using floats vs doubles etc. Main weight comes from the volume of long lat positions and their meta data, the meta data has been reviewed already.

Comment: @sergey ... You could probably shave half the bytes off the floats by using int16 with scaling factors ... Depending on your required precision. Have you considered compressing the larger meta data?

Comment: SSIS can call .NET code through a Script Task or a Script Transform.

Comment: @Grantly compressing large meta data - how would one look like? I mean, the data has to be directly accessible by the libraries without having to deflate it? Unless by compressing you mean normalising it. The int16 is a good shout, thank you, I can try and normalise various aspects of my app once more, but the elephant is kinda still there - normalising it would just make the room bigger, but the elephant will grow with time.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for the pointer. That sounds promising. But then it spills into deployment changes and most probably licensing cost, as SSIS is most likely, comprehensively, available on more expensive versions of SQL Server than current (free - Express). Good to know I can do it there though as an option.

Comment: You're right. Only "Standard" and above.

Comment: Did you consider a simple DataReader that streams a row at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as iterating through a very large data set that is too large to fit in memory goes, you can use a producer-consumer model. I used something like this when I was working with a custom data set that contained billions of records--about 2 terabytes of data total.

The idea is to have a single class that contains both producer and consumer. When you create a new instance of the class, it spins up a producer thread that fills a constrained concurrent queue. And that thread keeps the queue full. The consumer part is the API that lets you get the next record.

You start with a shared concurrent queue. I like the .NET [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.

Here's an example that reads a text file and maintains a queue of 10,000 text lines.

```
public class TextFileLineBuffer
{
    private const int QueueSize = 10000;
    private BlockingCollection<string> _buffer = new BlockingCollection<string>(QueueSize);
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelToken;
    private StreamReader reader;

    public TextFileLineBuffer(string filename)
    {
        // File is opened here so that any exception is thrown on the calling thread. 
        _reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        _cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        // start task that reads the file
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessFile, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public string GetNextLine()
    {
        if (_buffer.IsCompleted)
        {
            // The buffer is empty because the file has been read
            // and all lines returned.
            // You can either call this an error and throw an exception,
            // or you can return null.
            return null;
        }

        // If there is a record in the buffer, it is returned immediately.
        // Otherwise, Take does a non-busy wait.

        // You might want to catch the OperationCancelledException here and return null
        // rather than letting the exception escape.

        return _buffer.Take(_cancelToken.Token);
    }

    private void ProcessFile()
    {
        while (!_reader.EndOfStream && !_cancelToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var line = _reader.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                // This will block if the buffer already contains QueueSize records.
                // As soon as a space becomes available, this will add the record
                // to the buffer.
                _buffer.Add(line, _cancelToken.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCancelledException)
            {
                ;
            }
        }
        _buffer.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _cancelToken.Cancel();
    }
}
```

That's the bare bones of it. You'll want to add a Dispose method that will make sure that the thread is terminated and that the file is closed.

I've used this basic approach to good effect in many different programs. You'll have to do some analysis and testing to determine the optimum buffer size for your application. You want something large enough to keep up with the normal data flow and also handle bursts of activity, but not so large that it exceeds your memory budget.

### IEnumerable modifications

If you want to support `IEnumerable<T>`, you have to make some minor modifications. I'll extend my example to support `IEnumerable<String>`.

First, you have to change the class declaration:

```
public class TextFileLineBuffer: IEnumerable<string>
```

Then, you have to implement [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public IEnumerator<String> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (var s in _buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        yield return s;
    }
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

With that, you can initialize the thing and then pass it to any code that expects an `IEnumerable<string>`. So it becomes:

```
var items = new TextFileLineBuffer(filename);
DoSomething(items);

void DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    foreach (var s in list)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the producer and consumer model and for sharing a working code example. Clean and tidy. However, is it possible to extend the consumer part, so that it can work without having to make an explicit call to GetNextLine method? My consumer (a method call) expects an IEnumerable and I cannot modify the internals of the method and therefore cannot call GetNextLine() unless this is called on my behalf by, say, overriding a method that the consumer method would call anyway, like by using a custom IEnumerator (and overriding its MoveNext()) on a custom IEnumerable? Regards!

Comment: @Sergey: The modifications required to support `IEnumerable<T>` are pretty simple. See my update.

Comment: Many thanks @Jim, this implementation should work pretty well from what I can read and I will give it an actual spin when I circle back to the problem next week. This data access model scales very well and I can use this on a large db with EF, for example. It's quite interesting to see what one can come up with when two separate 'things' are put together!

Answer (score 2):

@Sergey The producer-consumer model is probably your safest solution (Proposed by Jim Mischel) for complete scalability.

However, if you were to increase the room for the elephant (using your visual metaphor that fits very well), then compression on the fly is a viable option. Decompress when used and discard after use, leaving the core data structure compressed in memory.  Obviously it depends on the data - how much it lends itself to compression, but there is a hell of alot of room in most data structures.  If you have ON and OFF flags for some meta data, this can be buried in the unused bits of 16/32 bit numbers, or at least held in bits not bytes; use 16 bit integers for lat / longs with a constant scaling factor to convert each to real numbers before use; strings can be compressed using winzip type libraries - or indexed so that only ONE copy is held and no duplicates exist in memory, etc....

Decompression (albeit custom made) on the fly can be lightning fast.

This whole process can be very laborious I admit, but can definitely keep the room large enough as the elephant grows  - in *some* instances.  (Of course, it may never be good enough if the data is simply growing indefinitely)

EDIT:  Re any sources...
Hi @Sergey, I wish I could!! Truly!  I have used this technique for data compression and really the whole thing was custom designed on a whiteboard with one or two coders involved.
Its certainly not (all) rocket science, but its good to fully scope out the nature of all the data, then you know (for example) that a certain figure will never exceed 9999, so then you can choose how to store it in minimum bits, and then allocate the left over bits (assuming 32 bit storage) to other values.  (A real world example is the number of fingers a person has...loosely speaking you could set an upper limit at 8 or 10, although 12 is possible, and even 20 is remotely feasible, etc if they have extra fingers.  You can see what I mean)  Lat / Longs are the PERFECT example of numbers that will never cross logical boundaries (unless you use wrap around values...).  That is, they are always in between -90 and +90 (just guessing which type of Lat Longs) - which is very easy to reduce / convert as the range of values is so neat.

So we did not rely 'directly' on any third party literature.  Only upon algorithms designed for specific types of data.

In other projects, for fast real time DSP (processing) the smarter (experienced game programmers) coders would convert floats to 16 bit ints and have a global scaling factor calculated to give max precision for the particular data stream (accelerometers, LVDT, Pressure gauges, etc) you are collecting.

This reduced the transmitted AND stored data without losing ANY information.  Similarly, for real time wave / signal data you could use (Fast) Fourier Transform to turn your noisy wave into its Amplitude, Phase and Spectrum components - literally half of the data values, without actually losing any (significant) data.  (Within these algorithms, the data 'loss' is completely measurable - so you can decide if you are in fact losing data)

Similarly there are algorithms like Rainfall Analysis (nothing to do with rain, more about cycles and frequency) which reduces your data alot.  Peak detection and vector analysis can be enough for some other signals, which basically throws out about 99% of the data...The list is endless, but the technique MUST be intimately suited to your data.  And you may have many different types of data, each lending itself to a different 'reduction' technique.  I'm sure you can google 'lossless data reduction' (although I think the term lossless is coined by music processing and a little misleading since digital music has already lost the upper and lower freq ranges...I digress)....Please post what you find (if of course you have the time / inclination to research this further)

I would be interested to discuss your meta data, perhaps a large chunk can be 'reduced' quite elegantly...

Comment: Hi @Grantly, many thanks for your contribution to my question. Yes, producer-consumer scales very well, and that is probably the most important goal at the moment. I haven't given compressing my data model much thought on the level you suggest, since like you say, it is likely to be laborious and I would need to do more testing afterwards to ensure the data is correct after decompression since I am doing simulations so the accuracy is important. Can you please include a link or two to a resource, for future read, where I can learn more about such data compressions and code examples? Regards

Comment: @Sergey - have added an EDIT to my answer, hope it helps